# Append number to filenames when flattening directory structure on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, directory-structure, flatten

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
/a/f.xml
/b/f.xml
/c/f.xml
/d/f.xml
```

What I want to do is copy all the xml files into one directory like this:

```
/e/f_0.xml
/e/f_1.xml
/e/f_2.xml
/e/f_3.xml
```

How can I do that efficiently on the Linux shell?

Comment: Do you want to always append a number, or only if the filenames would otherwise collide?  Are you committed to a shell script, or is a Perl, Python, or similar scripting language acceptable?  (If not, is bash fine or only POSIX sh?)

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified this more: Every subdirectory contains the same filenames, so yes, the number should be appended to every file. I hoped for a pure shell script solution, but id needn't be POSIX only, so bash would be fine, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let count=0
for file in $(ls $dir)
do
mv $file $newdir/${file%%.*}_$count.${file##*.}
let count=count+1
done
```

Comment: @ennuikiller: that's a cool one...shouldnt that ls be recursive to pick out the *.xml...?? +1 from me :D

Comment: why not use something like `find $dir -type f -name "*.xml"` in place of `ls $dir`?

Comment: Don't use `ls` and you shouldn't use `for` either. Pipe `find` into `while`. Also, this doesn't recurse into the source directories and it picks up all the files rather than just the xml files.

Comment: @dennis,@jschier
"Every subdirectory contains the same filenames, so yes, the number should be appended to every file"  - op 

and yes while in general is preferred because it deals with spaces in filenames, but it is not necessary in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0;
for i in */f.xml;
do
    BASE=`expr "$i" : '.*/\(.*\)\..*'`;
    EXT=`expr "$i" : '.*/.*\.\(.*\)'`;
    mv "$i" e/"$BASE"_"$COUNTER"."$EXT";
    COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /{a,b,c,d}/f.xml
do
    name=${file##*/}
    name=${name%.xml}
    ((i++))
    echo mv "$file" "/destination/${name}_${i}.xml"
done
```

bash 4.0 (for recursive)

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in /path/**/f.xml
do
    name=${file##*/}
    name=${name%.xml}
    ((i++))
    echo mv "$file" "/destination/${name}_${i}.xml"
done
```